# Sqlite DELETE trigger with foreign key

Tags: sqlite, triggers, android-sqlite, inner-join, android-room

I've got a simple scheme:[image: scheme]

Basically, I have an incomerecord and incometype and since its a n-n relationship I've got an additional table to track which and how many types of income an incomerecord has.

What I am trying to do is when a delete an `IncomeRecordWithTypeValue` record I want to check if there are any entities left with the IncomeRecord FOREIGN KEY, if not I want to delte the IncomeRecord.

My current approach looks like this:

```
database.execSQL(
"CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS Trigger_IncomeTypeIncomeRecordDelete " +
"AFTER DELETE ON IncomeRecordWithTypeValue " +
"BEGIN DELETE FROM IncomeRecord " +
"WHERE ( SELECT * FROM IncomeRecordWithTypeValue WHERE IncomeRecordWithTypeValue.incomeRecordId = IncomeRecord.id " +
"HAVING COUNT(*) = 0)" +
"END");
```

However, I receive the following syntax error:

```
BETWEEN, IN, LIMIT, ORDER or semicolon expected, got 'END'
```

What am I doing wrong? My approach is not that bad right? My other approach was using inner join but I basically receive the same error

Comment: Pay close attention to the syntax: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use NOT EXISTS to check if there is no other row left in `IncomeRecordWithTypeValue` with the `incomeRecordId` of the deleted row:

```
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS Trigger_IncomeTypeIncomeRecordDelete 
AFTER DELETE ON IncomeRecordWithTypeValue  
BEGIN 
  DELETE FROM IncomeRecord   
  WHERE id = OLD.incomeRecordId 
    AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM IncomeRecordWithTypeValue tv WHERE tv.incomeRecordId = IncomeRecord.id); 
END;
```